# How to call a web service from the other project or solution in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, web

I want to call a web service using the JQuery-Ajax. I know in your local folder, you can do that, how about if I transfer my web service to other project. What is the code?

I tried to change the URL but it gives me a request method: OPTION.

Comment: _"What is the code?"_ that's the stuff you write to solve a problem that you have a thorough understanding of. What your problem is, is a bit unclear. Please show what you have tried and the exact things that happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have search How to Consume `Webservice` to other project. For Example if you are running your `webservice` in your system, it will give you `URL` like this

```
http://localhost:54808/WebSite4/Service.asmx

http://127.0.0.1/WebSite4/Service.asmx
```

If you want to consume your `webservice` to other project you have to host your `webservice` or you need to have webserver to do this.

to consume your `webservice` you have to use Your `system Network IP address`

**Example:**

```
http://192.2.0.1/WebSite4/Service.asmx
```

by using this `URL` ,you can consume it in any other project according to you convenient.